# Find the length of the part of the astroid $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 1$ which is contained in the second quadrant (x ≤ 0, y ≥ 0).

Tags: vectors, parametric, parametrization

Find the length of the part of the astroid $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 1$
which is contained in the second quadrant (x ≤ 0, y ≥ 0).

The textbook starts the solution by giving the following parameterisation:

> First we look for a parameterisation of the astroid. We see that
>   $x^{1/3}$ and $y^{1/3}$ are on a circle of radius $1$, so we have the
>   usual parameterisation $(x^{1/3}, y^{1/3}) = (\cos(t), \sin(t))$.
>   Therefore, we choose the parameterisation $r(t) = (\cos^3(t),
> > \sin^3(t))$.

I understand that, when parameterising using polar coordinates, we usually set $x = \rho\cos(t)$ and $y = \rho\sin(t)$. However, I do not understand the reasoning behind the parameterisation done in the solution: Why do they use $x^{1/3}$ and $y^{1/3}$ when we have $x^{2/3}$ and $y^{2/3}$ in the equation of the asteroid?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this point.

Comment: because the equation of the unit circle is $x^2+y^2=1$, with parametrization $x=\cos t, y=\sin t$. here, you have $(x^{1/3})^2+(y^{1/3})^2=1$, so you set $x^{1/3}=\cos t$, etc.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Ahh, that makes sense. Thank you very much for the assistance.